# Anakin, Obi-Wan and Dooku are a match for Sidious!

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

Darth Sidious is too powerful. Anakin and Obi-Wan discusses and convinces Count Dooku (Darth Tyrannus) to fight against his own master. It is the only way they can be a true match against the Dark Lord of the Sith.

I want you to solve this epic fight in **Base10 alphametic, without the usage of computer**, with every details! There is only 1 solution I did(if I am not mistaken). Good luck, have fun!

```
 ANAKIN
 OBIWAN
+ DOOKU
-------
SIDIOUS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_i$ be the sum of the digits in the $i$th column.  Let $C_i$ be the carry over from $S_i + C_{i-1}$ and let $D_i$ be the resulting digit from $S_i$.

Since the result is one more digit than the others, we know that $S_6 \ge 10$.  At most, $C_5=2$, so at most $A+O+2=19$.

### Thus, we know that $S=1$

From $S_1=2N+U$, we know that $U$ must be odd.  Also, $N\notin\{0,5\}$ since either result in $U=S$.  Also, since $S=1$ there must be a carry over so $C_1 \in \{1,2\}$.

We can see $S_5=N+B+D+C_4$ and $D_5=D$.  Since $C_5=1$, $N+B+C_4=10$.

Similarly, $S_4=A+I+O+C_3$ and $D_4=I$, so $A+O+C_3=10$ and $C_4=1$.

Lastly, $S_3=K+W+O+C_2$ and $D_3=O$, so $K+W+C_2=10$ and $C_3=1$.

Since $C_3=1$, $S_4=A+O+C_3=10 \implies A+O=9$. Since $C_5=1$ we know;

### Therefore $I=0$

Also, $N+B+C_4=10 \implies N+B=9$.

Since $I=0$, $S_2=I+A+K+C_1=A+K+C_1$.  Thus, $C_2 \in \{0,1\}$.

Let go with the remaining odd values of $U$.

- If $U=3$, then $N\in\{4,9\}$ and $B\in\{5,0\}$. 0 is already taken, so $N=4$ and $B=5$.  Thus, $C_1=1$ and $S_2=A+K+C_1=A+K+1$ yields 3.  Thus, $A+K=12$.  But no remaining values allow for unique $A$ and $K$.
- If $U=7$, then $N=2$ and $B=7$.

So, $U\in\{5,9\}$.

#### Assume $U=5$

$N\in\{2,7\}$ and $B\in\{7,2\}$. If $N=2$ than $C_1=1$ and $A+K+C_1=A+K+1$ yields 5.  Thus, $A+K\in\{4,14\}$.  4 doesn't work, but 14 needs $A$ and $K$ to be $\{6,8\}$. Also, $C_2=1$, so $K+W+1=10 \implies K+W=9$.  Thus, $W\in\{3,1\}$, but 1 is already taken, so $W=3$, $K=6$, $A=8$.  But $A=8 \implies O=2$.

### Thus $U=9$

$N\in\{1,6\}$ and $B\in\{8,3\}$.  But $S=1$, so $N=6$ and $B=3$.  Thus, $C_1=2$ and $S_2=A+K+C_1=A+K+2$ yields 9 and $C_2=0$.  We can't get 19 with the remaining values, so it must be $A+K+2=9 \implies A+K=7$.

The only values for $A$ and $K$ are $\{2,5\}$.  Since $K+W+C_2=10$, we know that $K+W=10$, so $K\ne 5$. Thus, $A=5$, $O=4$, $K=2$, and $W=8$. Leaving only $D=7$.

```
 565206
 430856
+ 74429
-------
1070491
```

Comment: gj, the same that I concluded after creating it.